# How can I use a Leiningen plugin before I deploy it to Clojars?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm developing a Leiningen plugin. Actually, I'm working on a patch to an existing Leiningen plugin. I've made some changes, and now I want to see if they work.

What do I do?

I made these changes to support another project I'm working on. I'd like to point that project at my local working copy of the plugin to test my changes, but I don't see a way to do that.

Leiningen offers checkout dependencies, which solve this problem for dependencies, but not for plugins. Is there an equivalent for plugins?

Comment: `lein install` is simple, and it is often easier than checkout dependencies for regular libs as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Publish your forked version with a different group-id, either to clojars or to your local repo (with `lein install`). Then, in the project that uses the plugin, depend on your new artifact-id instead of the public one.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was missing. (I've been trying to `lein deploy` to my local repo. It hasn't been fun.) :)